# How can I mock out this python function properly?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have the following function in a file called my_file.py:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class MyClass:
    def my_func(self):
        print("Entered my_func()")
        print("log.error = {}".format(log.error))
        log.error("Hello World")
```

When `my_func()` is run, I see this output:

```
Entered my_func()
log.error =  <bound method ProcessAwareLogger.error of <celery.utils.log.ProcessAwareLogger object at 0x7fd52d4f0d50>>
```

I want to write a unit-test case to check that whenever `my_func()` is called, `log.error()` is called with the argument `"Hello World"`.

So my test case looks like this:

```
import mock
from my_file import MyClass

@mock.patch("my_file.logging.error")
def test_parse_response_with_error(self, mock_log_error):
    m = MyClass()
    m.my_func()
    mock_log_error.assert_called_once_with("Hello World")
```

When I run this test case, I get the error: `AssertionError: Expected to be called once. Called 0 times.` So my patch apparently didn't work. Did I specify the path `my_file.logging.error` wrong? How can I make this work properly so that the unit-test case passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mocked the wrong thing. `log.error` creates a bound method that is distinct from `logging.error`, and that method already has a reference to the "real" `logging.error` saved before your patch was created.

Instead, mock the `error` attribute of the `Logger` instance directly.

```
@mock.patch.object(my_file.log, 'error'):
def test_it(self, mock_log_error):
    m = MyClass()
    m.my_func()
    mock_log_error.assert_called_once_with("Hello World")
```

(It's possible that patching `logging.error` *before* importing `my_file` might work.)